# Gradient starts to early

Tags: swift, gradient

This is my code:

```
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.opacity = 0.8
    let startColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
    let endColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
    gradient.colors = [startColor, endColor, startColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.1, 0.95]
    gradient.frame = viewInStack1Background.frame
    viewInStack1Background.layer.addSublayer(gradient)

    let gradient2 = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient2.colors = [startColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor, startColor]
    gradient2.locations = [0.0, 0.1, 0.95]
    gradient2.opacity = 0.8
    gradient2.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient2.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient2.frame = viewInStack1Background.frame
    viewInStack1Background.layer.addSublayer(gradient2)
```

I want a red color on the outside and a green color on the inside. It looks like this now:

[image]

Why is there so much red when the start location is set to 0.95? Thanks.

Comment: Your gradient is `red-clear-red` at `0-0.1-0.95`. There's a lot of space to transition from clear to red on the second segment. Maybe changing it to `red-clear-clear-red` at `0-0.1-0.85-0.95`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
```

That transitions to full green in the middle -- right now you have full green at 10% near the left.  If you want to transition faster to green, then try

```
gradient.colors = [startColor, endColor, endColor, startColor]
gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.05, 0.95, 1.0]
```